# UICollectionViewController moveItemAtIndexPath - how to know when done dragging

Tags: ios, ios9

I need to get an event/information when CollectionView is starting and stopping dragging.

I think this must be a normal scenario when dragging cells around - to be able to save the list behind the CollectionView.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
   moveItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
           toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath{
```

Answer (score 2):

Idea #1:

Use below two delegate methods :-

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

//Method Signature Changed for Swift 3

```
func collectionView(UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt: IndexPath) {

}
```

Idea #2:
UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView. So if you have set the delegate and implemented UIScrollViewDelegate, you should be able to detect this the same way as UIScrollView

Check in this function:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
}
```

This should work..

Cheers!

Comment: willDisplayCell  is called alright, but not didEndDisplayingCell

Comment: Thanks, but still same thing.

Answer (score 0):

use this methods to get start scrolling and end scrolling of collection view:

```
 func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

 }

 func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

 }
```